# from an array make an object with keys in the form of a name and values and return it

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a array `banks`
and I need to return one object with all the parameters described below

```
const banks = [{kod: 723,name: "bank",},{kod: 929,name: "bank2"}]
```

i tried to do it with

```
const lookup = banks.map(item => {
  return ({[item.kod]: item.name }) 
})
```

but it returns the result `[ {723: "bank"}, {929: "bank2"} ]`

how can i achieve this result  `{723: "bank",929: "bank2"}`

Comment: You can't do it with `.map()` because the whole point is to *map* elements of an existing array into elements of a new array. You can however use `.reduce()` as in the posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like so:

```js
const banks = [{kod: 723,name: "bank",},{kod: 929,name: "bank2"}];

const res = banks.reduce((acc, {kod, name}) => ({...acc, [kod]: name}), {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` instead

```js
const banks = [{kod: 723,name: "bank",},{kod: 929,name: "bank2"}]

const lookup = banks.reduce((op,item) => {
  op[item.kod] =  item.name
  return op
},{})

console.log(lookup)
```

Comment: oh, I completely forgot about the ```reduce``` method, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You could take the result and assign all parts to a new object.

```js
const
    banks = [{ kod: 723, name: "bank" }, { kod: 929, name: "bank2" }],
    lookup = Object.assign({}, ...banks.map(({ kod, name }) => ({ [kod]: name })));

console.log(lookup);
```